# CX innovatory storage integration in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm developing an iPhone app where I'm integrating CX cloud storage so that I can store images and audio files. I"m trying to load login page on `UIWebView` but its giving me error.

here is my code

```
    NSURL *loginUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"
    https://www.cx.com/mycx/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@",clientID,redirectURi]];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loginUrl];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I'm getting following error

> Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)" UserInfo=0x68102e0 {}

Answer (score 0):

The CX innovatory has been discontinued. 
Sorry for the inconvenience!